# Overflow Hidden does not appear to be working

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where `overflow:hidden;` does not seem to be working.

I am trying to make it such that several inline elements wrapped in a div get cut off through `overflow: hidden;` at 20 pixels

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Hello World 1</span>
    <span>Hello World 2</span>
    <span>Hello World 3</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7XHPC/

The code shows the Hello World inline elements wrapping around the container and not getting cut off via `overflow: hidden;`

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the `.container`

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/x6VSL/1/

Comment: i think OP wants each word one below the other.

Comment: @Alek if that's the case then why is OP asking this question

Comment: OP said inline elements..?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want each word one below the other so i suggest this:

**css**

```
.container {
  max-width:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:table-cell;
}

div > span{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6VSL/3/)

Comment: You don't actually need display:table-cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with two wrapper divs

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-container"> 
    <div class="container">
        <span>Hello World 1</span>
        <span>Hello World 2</span>
        <span>Hello World 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer-container {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XHPC/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width to the span tags, and also make them display as block.

```
.container {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container span {
    width:200px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a height.  Otherwise the height automatically adjusts to fit the content.

CSS:

```
 .container {
     width: 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 50px;
 }
```